# Parsing image from raw data in OpenCV fails

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, decode

Im trying to load a QImage and cv::Mat as efficient as possible.

Im doing this by first opening the image file, and loading it into a QByteArray, then parsing that with QImage, and cv::imread individually.

The QImage gets parsed just fine, but the cv::Mat never gets decoded, it keeps returning null...

Ive tried CV_8UC3, but that throws an error:

```
OpenCV(4.2.0) /opencv/main/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:732: error: (-215:Assertion failed) buf.checkVector(1, CV_8U) > 0 in function 'imdecode_'
```

Help?

```
bool ImageUtils::ReadCVandQT(const QString& fileName, QImage& qtImageOut, cv::Mat cvImageOut, const char* format)
{
    // Open file
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        return false;

    // Get file data
    QByteArray byteArray = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    // Get QImage
    qtImageOut = QImage::fromData(byteArray, format);
    if (qtImageOut.isNull())
        return false;

    // Get cv::Mat ===FAILS HERE===
    cvImageOut = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, byteArray.size(), CV_8U, byteArray.data()), cv::IMREAD_COLOR | cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);

    // This always returns false
    if (cvImageOut.data == nullptr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Edit:

The images i am trying to load can be any format, so need to decode them

I could also convert it from a QImage to a cv::Mat using this:

```
if (qimage.format() == QImage::Format_RGB888) {
    return cv::Mat(qimage.height(), qimage.width(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t*)qimage.constBits(), qimage.bytesPerLine());
} else {
    QImage rgb888 = qimage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
    return cv::Mat(rgb888.height(), rgb888.width(), CV_8UC3, (uint8_t*)rgb888.constBits(), rgb888.bytesPerLine());
}
```

But that has its own set of problems

Comment: If the image is RAW you don't have to dcode it . Once you have the pointer with the data you can copy it (`memcpy` maybe) to the `Mat` instance created as `img.create(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CV_8UC1)`. For example:  `memcpy(img.data, imagedata, framesize)`

Comment: It isnt tho, its can be a jpg, png, bmp, tiff, etc...

Comment: True, I thought you had a raw file

Comment: The `Mat` you create as an input to `imdecode` needs to have 1 column, 1 channel, and as many rows as there are bytes in the source byte array. Yours has the row and column count swapped. That's what the assertion tells you (or rather what `checkVector` checks).

Comment: @DanMašek It still doesnt work:
cvImageOut = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(byteArray.size(), 1, CV_8U, byteArray.data()), cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

Comment: How exactly does it not work in that case? You get assert? `cvImageOut` in the function doesn't hold the correct image after the `imdecode`? Or after the function returns, the `Mat` outside it doesn't get changed? | Note that you pass `cvImageOut` by value. Then you assign it the result of `imdecode`, which make the `Mat` refer to a new buffer, and the original (shared) doesn't get changed. (`Mat` works like a shared pointer). You need to pass it by reference for the changes to propagate outside the function.

Comment: @DanMašek The mat returned from cv::imdecode() is empty, this happens on normal images that Qt parses without any problems